# error getting data with Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable

I was a problem and I see no way to fix it (I've tried them all). 
I did the Parcelable class to send an array of objects with intent. In the first activity I send this array of objects. In the second activity I send a whole, and I pick up in the third activity. 
And it turns out, it gives me an error when capturing the whole, and nothing Application open, you do not understand closes, since the error I get is the third activity that fails to do so. If I comment the line to pick up the entire activity in terce not get me wrong, and I also pass the array with objects perfectly well. But I also need the whole of the second activity. 
Leave the code to see what you think.

Sending the array of ob. first Activity

```
>  //creamos el intent y le pasamos la clase a mostrar
            Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            Bundle contenedor= new Bundle();

            //le cargamos al bundle un objeto parceable que se almacenara
            //bajo la key "array" y contendrá nuestra lista
            contenedor.putParcelable("array",lista_musica);
            //cargamos el intent con el bundle
            i.putExtras(contenedor);
            //lanzamos el intent
            startActivity(i);
```

Sending the entire Second Activity

> Intent ii=new Intent(Generos.this,MainActivity.class);
>
> ii.putExtra("sentGeneroId", generoId);

startActivity(ii);

Collect data from the Third Activity

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if (b != null) {
```

`lista_musica = b.getParcelable("array");
generoId = (Integer) b.get("sentGeneroId");
}`

```
Log.i("mi error","el generoID: "+generoId);

Log.i("mi error","el ARRAY del main: "+lista_musica);
```

The Parcelable class not think this wrong, as I said previously mentioned line

> generoId = (Integer) b.get ("sentGeneroId");

does not give me error and sends me correctly the array of objects. I've tried everything. I managed not to leave me the error uncommented that line, but the array in the third activity was always null, but no longer or what I did ............. 
You see if someone with more sight I know that fails. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

In your SecondActivity you pass generoId as **String** out side **Bundle** so you get this value directly from **Intent** instead of **Intent Bundle**.

```
generoId = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("sentGeneroId"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the same error keeps coming. I have to say that before creating the code of the first activity, the entire shipping did me correctly. The problem arises when you create me sending the array of objects. 
It seems that the two can not be together. If I send just the array of objects, it does well. And if I send only the whole of the second Activity also does well. But if I want to send both, I get this error ........... 
I'm desperate.

Answer (score 0):

seems that the first Activity, when sending the array of objects, automatically starts receiving data from third Activity. And of course, fails to receive the whole, that until the second Activity does not send it out. Mark it as error trying to get something and nothing. 
I tried sending the first array to the second Activity, and what it does is initiate me the second activity, bypassing the first. 
So far I had not found this problem ..........